# If I script a GPL software like GDB using its scripting API, should my scripts be distributed as GPL as well?

Tags: gpl, api

GDB is using GPL. I am writing scripts/python commands using its python scripting API and importing `gdb`: the module they expose for that goal.

Should my scripts be also distributed under GPL? Or can i distribute them as closed source part of a proprietary product?

EDIT: Adding some details:

We have many python modules that use the gdb api in various ways, exposing "commands" implementing domain-related functionality to the upper layers of our non-released product.
Those layers communicate with the gdb process using stdin and files (but our own scripts run in the gdb process)

The gdb api is exposed as a python api with classes and methods/functions that we directly call in our code:

- https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Python-API.html
- https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb.html/Basic-Python.html#Basic-Python

Comment: Please amend your question and provide more details about your script and how it interacts with GDB, for those of us, who are not familiar with the API.

Comment: thank you @Martin_in_AUT: I added some details, I can add more if needed